# IE 11 Jquery Hover is not working document.load event or document.ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, load

All

Following code is not working with Internet Explorer. As I would like render hover event on class in document.load or document.ready event. But i could not succeed

```js
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    var maxHeight = 250;
    jQuery(".dropdown").hover(
        function () {
            jQuery("li.firstmenu ul li").removeClass("XYZ");
            jQuery("li.firstmenu ul li").removeClass("ABC");
            jQuery('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("500");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('openDemo');
            jQuery(this).addClass("active-Demo");
            jQuery("div#MegaMenu").find("li.secondLI").removeClass("DEF").addClass("hideJIJO");
            //jQuery('.active-global-tab > a').removeClass("default-fontcolorD").addClass("default-fontcolorB");

            jQuery('ul.dropdown-menu > li.col-sm-4').each(function () {
                jQuery(this).height(maxHeight);
            });

        },
        function () {

            jQuery('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("500");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');

            jQuery(this).removeClass("active-tab");
            //jQuery('.global-nav-item > a').removeClass("default-fontcolorB").addClass("default");
        }
    );
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.onload instead.

This method automatically called when page load.

Example

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    var maxHeight = 250;
    jQuery(".dropdown").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery("li.firstmenu ul li").removeClass("XYZ");
            jQuery("li.firstmenu ul li").removeClass("ABC");
            jQuery('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("500");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('openDemo');
            jQuery(this).addClass("active-Demo");
            jQuery("div#MegaMenu").find("li.secondLI").removeClass("DEF").addClass("hideJIJO");
            //jQuery('.active-global-tab > a').removeClass("default-fontcolorD").addClass("default-fontcolorB");

            jQuery('ul.dropdown-menu > li.col-sm-4').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).height(maxHeight);
            });

        },
        function() {

            jQuery('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("500");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');

            jQuery(this).removeClass("active-tab");
            //jQuery('.global-nav-item > a').removeClass("default-fontcolorB").addClass("default");
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `you can use PageLoad instead. This method automatically called when page load.` No it isn't - unless you call it yourself, but then the logic flow would be identical to what the OP already has